# Signal handler not working on process opened via pipe

Tags: c++, pipe, signals

Note: this is a general question (not limited to `wolfram` command, and you don't have to know about `wolfram`).

I consider wrapping `wolfram` (CUI calculator like python interpreter). Without any wrapper, `SIGINT` causes the program to suspend the calculation.

```sh
$ /usr/bin/wolfram -noinit

In[1] := While[True, 1] #start infinite loop
#execute `kill -SIGINT` from another shell to send SIGINT
Interrupt> #calculation now interrupted (you can cancel or resume it)
```

However, with a wrapper, `SIGINT` causes `wolfram` to exit right now.

```sh
$ ./wrapper.out

In[1] := While[True, 1] #start infinite loop
#execute `kill -SIGINT` (the target is not the wrapper but the `wolfram` itself)   
#`wolfram` exits right away
Caught SIGPIPE. #the wrapper recieves SIGPIPE
```

The full code of the wrapper is here. (The actual code is written better without `exit(0)` and with a smart pointer, but the simplified code below still causes the problem.)

```cpp
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    if (signal == SIGINT) {
        cout << "Caught SIGINT.\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Caught SIGPIPE.\n";
    }
    exit(0); //not good since destructors aren't called
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    //set a signal handler
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGPIPE, signal_handler);

    FILE *pipe = popen("/usr/bin/wolfram -noinit", "w");

    while (true) {

        string buf;
        getline(cin, buf);

        fprintf(pipe, "%s\n", buf.c_str());
        fflush(pipe);

    }

    pclose(pipe);

}
```

Why, with a wrapper, is the signal handler of piped process ignored? And how can I keep the functionality of the original signal handler? `man 3 popen` didn't give me any hint.

Comment: You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  Using any C++ streams objects is **not** async-signal-safe.  Nor is `exit()` async-signal-safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So I wrote "The actual code is written better without `exit(0)`". I know `exit()` has many problems. In the actual code, I set a proper flag with `std::mutex` when signal is sent and read it from `main()` to correctly terminate the program. But such a detail has not to do with my question, I think (because the problem occurs **before** the call of wrapper's signal handler).

Comment: If you read `wolfram`'s documentation, you're likely to find something somewhere mentioning that if `wolfram` detects that its standard input is not an interactive terminal, its behavior changes. Your pipe is not an interactive terminal. Since you know how to use `man`, go pull up the man page for `isatty`. `wolfram` likely `isatty(0)`-s, and since it determines that the standard input is not a terminal, it will exit instead of issuing another prompt when it gets a `SIGINT`. I am not familiar with this program, but this is the obvious behavior, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If so, is there any way to tell a lie "I'm terminal" to the command? `wolfram` is not an open source software, so I cannot change the implementation.

Comment: @ynn `std::mutex` is not safe in a signal handler either-

Comment: @ynn what makes you think the signal handler of the child is ignored. You interrupt the child and then the parent tries to `write(2)` to its interrupted child. You have to read the manuals of `pipe` and `write` to find out what the expected semantics of this is. It seems that the parent receives a `SIGPIPE` and you call `exit` on it. This will send a `SIGCHLD` to all children and wolfram might very well decide to stop its further execution on this signal. If not, its reads from stdin will receive a `SIGPIPE` also because the pipe has been closed by the parent.

Comment: @tos-1 I'm afraid you may misunderstand the order. In my case, 1) child is calculating, and wrapper is waiting for input, 2) send SIGINT to child and wrapper is waiting for input, 3) child is terminated (`ps` says so) and wrapper is waiting for input. Just these. Essentially, the wrapper's signal handler is not related. Of course, pushing enter key after the 3rd step causes the wrapper to write to the broken pipe. You may assume the child is killed **after** the parent's signal handler is called, but in my case, child is killed **before** that. `SIGPIPE` is irrelevant. I wanna avoid 3rd step.

Comment: Yes, you can simulate a terminal using a pseudo-tty device. See the `pty` manual page for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Finally I succeeded in making signals work by using a pty. Thank you really much.