# Double echo when running commands under a pty

Tags: c++, ssh, tty, pty

I'm writing a program to create a pty, then fork and execute an `ssh` command with the slave side of the pty as its `stdin`. The full source code is here.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {

    int fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
    grantpt(fd);
    unlockpt(fd);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) { //slave

        freopen(ptsname(fd), "r", stdin);

        execlp("ssh", "ssh", "user@192.168.11.40", NULL);

    } else { //master

        FILE *f = fdopen(fd, "w");
        string buf;

        while (true) {

            getline(cin, buf);

            if (!cin) {
                break;
            }

            fprintf(f, "%s\n", buf.c_str());

        }

    }

}
```

After executing this program and inputting just `echo hello` (and a newline), the child command re-sends my input before its own output, thus duplicating my input line:

```
~ $ echo hello
echo hello #duplication
hello

~ $
```

I think this is due to the fact that a pty behaves almost the same as a normal terminal. If I add `freopen("log.txt", "w", stdout);"` and input the same command, I get just

```
echo hello #This is printed because I typed it.
```

and the contents of `log.txt` is this:

```
~ $ echo hello #I think this is printed because a pty simulates input.
hello                             

~ $
```

How can I avoid the duplication?

---

**Is that realizable?**

I know it is somehow realizable, but don't know how to. In fact, the `rlwrap` command behaves the same as my program, except that it doesn't have any duplication:

```
~/somedir $ rlwrap ssh user@192.168.11.40
~ $ echo hello
hello

~ $
```

I'm reading the source code of `rlwrap` now, but haven't yet understood its implementation.

---

**Supplement**

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803703/the-meaning-of-disabling-local-echo-in-terminal) (To me, not the answer but the OP was helpful.), unsetting the `ECHO` terminal flag disables the double echoing. In my case, adding this snippets to the slave block solved the problem.

```
termios terminal_attribute;
int fd_slave = fileno(fopen(ptsname(fd_master), "r"));
tcgetattr(fd_slave, &terminal_attribute);
terminal_attribute.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
tcsetattr(fd_slave, TCSANOW, &terminal_attribute);
```

It should be noted that this is not what  `rlwrap` does. As far as I tested `rlwrap <command>` never duplicates its input line for any `<command>`  However, my program echoes twice for some `<command>`s. For example,

```
~ $ echo hello
hello #no duplication

~ $ /usr/bin/wolfram
Mathematica 12.0.1 Kernel for Linux ARM (32-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= 3 + 4                                                                   
        3 + 4 #duplication (my program makes this while `rlwrap` doesn't)

Out[1]= 7

In[2]:=
```

Is this because the `<command>` (`ssh` when I run `wolfram` remotely) re-enables echoing? Anyway, I should keep reading the source code of `rlwrap`.

Comment: Does `rlwrap` *create* a pseudoterminal, or just use its terminal interface to drive a pipe?

Comment: (`rlwrap` author here:) As you already oberved, after the child has called `exec` the terminal flags of the slave side are not under your control anymore, and the child may (and often will) re-enable echo. Both `rlwrap` and `rlfe` solve the problem in their own (different) ways: either remove your own input before displaying the child's output, or do _not_ display the first line of this output. I'm voting to re-open the question in order to give a proper answer

Comment: @HansLub Wow. I'm really glad to get a comment from the original author. I tried to *remove your own input before displaying the child's output* before I posted this question, but not succeeded maybe due to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420424/why-does-ssh-t-option-adds-cr-lf-in-redirected-output). By the way, finally I found there is `-rawterm` option for `wolfram` which avoids the command's re-enabling echoing.

Comment: @HansLub The reason why I'm trying to write a program which is similar to `rlwrap` is `rlwrap` doesn't work with `ssh -t <host> /usr/bin/wolfram`. Now I implemented `rl` ([GitHub](https://github.com/your-diary/Rl)) which has really less functionality than `rlwrap` but works with the command. `rlwrap` works with `ssh <host> /usr/bin/wolfram` (here, not with `-t`) but, in my case, `-t` is needed to send a signal to `/usr/bin/wolfram` through `ssh` (c.f. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015738/signal-handler-not-working-on-process-opened-via-pipe)).

Comment: `wolfram` (without the `-rawterm`) includes control characters in its prompt, which confuses `rlwrap`. Using `-rawterm` to prevent this, and the `-a` (or `--always-readline`) `rlwrap` option (to make `rlwrap` use `readline` even when `wolfram` puts its teminal in raw mode will make `rlwrap` usable.   For me, `rlwrap -a -pRed ssh -t localhost /usr/bin/wolfram -rawterm` seems to work well  at first sight.
That said, `rlwrap` was designed for simple console programs without line editing and history.  `wolfram` hardly fits this description.

Comment: @HansLub Thank you. `-a` and `-rawterm` also worked on my environment. I should have seen the manpage (or [this issue](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/74)) of `rlwrap` to find the existence of `-a` option. I've learned much in writing my original `rl` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already observed, after the child has called `exec()` the terminal flags of the slave side are not under your control anymore, and the child may (and often will) re-enable echo. This means that is is not of much use to change the terminal flags in the child before calling `exec`.

Both [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) and [rlfe](https://github.com/issuu/readline/tree/master/examples/rlfe) solve the problem in their own (different) ways:

- `rlfe` keeps the entered line, but [removes the echo'ed input](https://github.com/issuu/readline/blob/cb40dfe14a3bb5389cc3ebce043d7eada01275e1/examples/rlfe/rlfe.c#L706) from the child's output before displaying it
- `rlwrap` [removes the entered line](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/blob/5bfd994c33624ba1ce9a3306cdbcca0dd6791f3c/src/readline.c#L201)  and lets it be replaced by the echo

Whatever approach you use, you have to know whether your input has been (in `rlfe`s case) or *will be* (in `rlwrap`s case) echoed back. `rlwrap`, at least, does this by *not* closing the pty's slave end in the parent process, and then watching its terminal settings (in this case, the `ECHO` bit in its `c_lflag`) to know whether the slave will echo or not.

All this is rather cumbersome, of course. The `rlfe` approach is probably easier, as it doesn't require the use of the `readline` library, and you could simply `strcmp()`  the received output with the input you just sent (which will only go wrong in the improbable case of a `cat` command that disables echo on its input)

Comment: I'll remember this awesome and technical implementation: *rlwrap, at least, does this by not closing the pty's slave end in the parent process, and then watching its terminal settings*